# WPF Textblock и LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, xaml

Мне нужно реализовать анимацию заполнения внутри `TextBlock.Foreground`, но так, что бы сверху был черный цвет, а снизу градиент по бокам. Ничего кроме как на картинке не выходит. Как можно такое реализовать?

[image: Градиент]

Код:

```xml
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           FontSize="74" FontWeight="Bold">
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop x:Name="WhiteOffset" Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop x:Name="GrayOffset" Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="WhiteOffset" From="0" To="1" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GrayOffset" From="0" To="1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
    Some Text
</TextBlock>
```

Получится должно в итоге вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите, как именно должно получиться

Comment: Так снизу или по бокам?

Comment: И покажите ваш код

Comment: Нижний градиент. Розовый и фиолетовый цвета должны быть по бокам, а черный сверху.

Comment: предполагаю, что тишина потому, что никто не может понять, что такое "по бокам и сверху", звучит как "вровень выпирать должно". Почему вы проигнорировали этот комментарий `Покажите, как именно должно получиться`?

Comment: Получится должно в итоге вот так:
https://imgur.com/a/qh79kh9

Comment: Одним LinearGradientBrush это сделать не получится. Так как вы задаете начальную и конечную точку. Соответственно тут из вариантов только сделать в несколько слоев с прозрачностью.